# Is it possible to assign the background colour of a FullCalendar event based on its title?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

As FullCalendar isn't able to read the colours that are assigned to events in Google Calendar I need to be able to style the way events are displayed based on the text content of the individual event titles.

Having read as many posts as I can find on the matter, it would seem that FullCalendar's 'eventRender' is the most likely route to take but the closest I can find to what I need is something along the lines of:-

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
                if(event.description == "blah blah") {
                    element.css('background-color', '#ff000');
```

My problem is, (a) I need eventRender to apply to the event titles rather than their descriptions, and (b) I need it to be a case of **'if the title *includes* the words blah-blah'**, rather than **'if the title is an *exact match* for blah blah'**.

I hope all the above isn't too garbled and nonsensical. I'm still very much feeling my way with all this; so any help, advice, thoughts, or steers in the right direction would be most gratefully received! :)

Many thanks, in advance, for your time.

Edited:
Additional info. The script that I'm using on the FullCalendar html page (sans API key and Google ID)

```
<script>

        $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            height: 'auto',
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'agendaDay,month',
            },

            eventRender: function(event, element) {
                if(event.description == "blah blah") {
                    element.css('background-color', '#ff000');
                }
            },

            // Google API key
            googleCalendarApiKey: 'xxxxxxxxx',

            // Diary Dates
            events: 'xxxxxxxxx',


            eventClick: function(event) {
                // opens events in a popup window
                window.open(event.url, 'gcalevent', 'width=700,height=600');
                return false;
            },

            loading: function(bool) {
                $('#loading').toggle(bool);
            }

        });

    });

    </script>
```

Comment: Could you provde a fiddle ? For your (b) problem, you can use .indexOf() instead of ==

Comment: Thanks for replying, Robin. I'm afraid I'm not very familiar with fiddle; so it'll take me a while to set something up for folk to have a look at (and to add to my woes Dreamweaver keeps crashing on me; so I'm a bit swamped at the mo').

If it helps, this is the script that I'm using on the FullCalendar html page (sans API key and Google ID)...

Comment: Apols Robin, I was adding the script via an edit of my original post at the same time that you were replying. I'll try your suggestion right now... two tics...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the eventRender callback

```
if(-1 != event.title.indexOf("blah blah")) {
    element.find('.fc-title').css('background-color', '#ff000'); 
}
```

will do it.

or better yet, apply a style `element.addClass("event-bg-class");`

Comment: Huge thanks for the reply, it's greatly appreciated... I'll give that a try right away and shout back with feedback asap :)

Comment: No joy. I'm generally pretty tenacious but after days of trying I'm afraid this one's got me totally beat. I'm sure it's something I'm doing wrong and/or am too stupid to fathom out. Thank you for your time and advice, though. It really was much appreciated. x

Comment: Nnnnnnnnngh! I gave it _one last_ go and as I did so, spotted that the colour should have been **#fff000** not **#ff000**. I should probably go into the study with the ivory-handled revolver and do the decent thing, now! A million thanks to both respondants for your (rock solid) advice!!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you basically try ?

```
if(-1 != event.title.indexOf("blah blah")) {
    element.css('background-color', '#ff000');
}
```

Comment: Many thanks but sadly that doesn't seem to work in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

# Hope it'll help you

## element.addClass("custom-event-0");

## element.addClass("custom-event-1");

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var eventsdata = [];
var i = 0;

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    height: 'auto',
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'agendaDay,month',
    },

    eventRender: function(event, element) {
        if(event.description == "blah blah") {
            element.css('background-color', '#ff000');
        }
    },

    // Google API key
    googleCalendarApiKey: 'xxxxxxxxx',

    // Diary Dates
    events: 'xxxxxxxxx',

    eventRender: function(event, element) {
        if(eventsdata.length == 0){
            eventsdata.push(event.title);
            i++;
        }else{
            var tmp = eventsdata.indexOf(event.title);
            if(tmp == -1){
                eventsdata.push(event.title);
                i++;
            }
        }
        element.addClass("custom-event-"+eventsdata.indexOf(event.title));
    },

    eventClick: function(event) {
        // opens events in a popup window
        window.open(event.url, 'gcalevent', 'width=700,height=600');
        return false;
    },

    loading: function(bool) {
        $('#loading').toggle(bool);
    }

});
```

Comment: Are you sure there's nothing wrong with the formatting? Those headlines look odd.